# laravel add multiple where and or where

Tags: mysql, laravel, loops, eloquent

```
[
    [ 
        [ 
        'condition1', 
        'value1',
        ],
        [ 
        'condition2', 
        'value2',
        ],
        [ 
        'condition3', 
        'value3',
        ],
    ], 
    [ 
    'condition4', 
    'value4',
    ],
    [

    ]

]
```

Im trying to build query builder with values 1 ,values 2, value 3 are in 'or' condition and value 4 in 'and' condition

for first two array i can get the result like what i need

```
$result = DB::table('table')
   ->where(function($query) use($value1) {
      $query->where('condition1', $value1) // and condition
            ->orWhere('condition2', $value2) // rest or in or condition
            ->orWhere('condition3', $value3)
   })
   ->where('condition4', $value4)
   ->get();
```

But the array will be keep going. inside the array index 0 is in 'and' condition and a;; other index in or condition

I have tried like

```
foreach($values as $value){ //
  $result->where(function ($qry) use ($value) { 
    foreach($value as $index=>$val){ 
    $qry->when($index==0),function($qyr){
       $qry->where();
    }
    },function($qry){
       $qry->orwhere();
    }
  });

}
```

Is there any better solution or improvement i can add?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have condition3 in the grouping query. Normaly it should look like this:

```
$result = DB::table('table')->where(function($query) use($value1, $value2) {
  $query->where('condition1', $value1) // where condition1
        ->orWhere('condition2', $value2); // or where condition2            
})->Where('condition3', $value3) // And where condition3
->get();
```